# Replace a string in table using jquery?

Tags: jquery

This is my table.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>I am Achinna</td>
    <td>I am Krish</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I need to place "Me" instead of "I am" using jquery.

Comment: $('td').contains("I am").each( function() { var str=$(this).text();

Comment: Just edit your question and add the complete code.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('td').each(function (i, el) {
  var txt = $(el).text();
  $(el).text(txt.replace(/(I\sam)\b/g, 'Me'));
});
```

Comment: Or easier: `$('table td').text(function(i, t) { return t.replace('I am', 'Me');});`

Comment: @VMAtm: Because this is how the function signature is defined. It is the index of the element in the set.

Comment: I amusingly note that using a space after "I am" may slightly mitigate the risk of false-positive matches against the very short pattern, such as the one that would be caused by the start of this sentence.

Comment: Hahaha well-demonstrated @aroth

Answer (score 2):

```
jQuery.each($("body").find("table"), function() {
    this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML.split("I am ").join("Me ");
});
```

Example:  http://jsfiddle.net/Yc3nK/

Comment: That will destroy all possible event handlers on the cells.

Comment: @Felix - Not all possible handlers, just handlers that were registered programmatically on the table's inner `tr`, `td`, and other content nodes.  Any handlers that were set up in the table markup itself would be preserved.  Besides, there are no such handlers in the example, and if someone is still using `<table>` it's a pretty safe bet that they are probably not configuring their event handlers programmatically, if they are using any at all.

Comment: What is wrong with `table`? How would present tabular data if not with a table? Yeah, of course it would not destroy the handlers set via HTML attributes. Still, setting the `innerHTML` is not a good approach imo. There are other more preservative ways that are easy too.

Comment: @Felix - There are a number of [articles](http://webdesign.about.com/od/layout/a/aa111102a.htm) on the subject of why not to use `table`.  Typically it comes down to ease/consistency of styling and maintainability/flexibility.  To show tabular data I would use `div` elements with "row" and "column" classes.

Comment: Well, of course you should not use tables for layout. But for data it is fine and it is what tables are for. It has a distinct semantic meaning which cannot be expressed with `div`s. Anyway, enough discussion ;)

Comment: Fair enough.  I just remember a time when everyone was using tables for *everything*, and I shudder.

Comment: @FelixKling let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1150/discussion-between-aroth-and-felix-kling)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#table tr').each(function() {
    var value = this.val();
    value.replace("I am", "Me");
    this.val(value);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('table td').each(function() {
    text = $(this).text();
    text.replace(/i am/i, 'Me');
    $(this).text(text);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("table:td").each(function(index) {
  $(this).text($(this).text().replace("I am", "Me"));
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I use this with my Kendo TreeList because a null issue still exists.

This only works if the background is white.

```
$('table td').each(function () {
    text = $(this).text();
    if (text == "null") {
       $(this).addClass("white");
    } else {
       $(this).removeClass("white");
    };



<style>
  .white {
    color: white;
}
</style>
```